# Rotate image while key down, in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, image, canvas, wpf-controls

I have an image that is inside a popup. When I am inside the canvas, and if a key is down I want to rotate the popup. My code doesnt update the rotation unless I leave the canvas (move mouse outside of canvas), then enter again (move mouse inside canvas). I confirmed the angle is being updated when the key is down inside the canvas, so I have no clue why it doesnt update unless I exit and reenter.

```
<Popup Name="floatingTip" 
       AllowsTransparency="True" 
       Placement="Relative" 
       PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=MainCanvas}">
    <Popup.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform CenterX="1" CenterY="1" Angle="{Binding Angle}"/>
    </Popup.RenderTransform>
    <Image Source="{Binding Name}"
           Width="{Binding Width}"
           Height="{Binding Height}"/>
</Popup>
```

When the mouse enters the canvas space, I set `CanvasIsActive = true`.
Here is the KeyDown event:

```
private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (CanvasIsActive && currentTool == "staticBrush") 
    {
        cursorImage.Angle += 20;
        this.Title = cursorImage.Angle.ToString();
    }
}
```

Here is my Angle property that is updated when a key is down:

```
double imgAngle;
public double Angle
{
    get { return imgAngle; }
    set
    {
        imgAngle = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Angle");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. To refresh the rotation inside the popup, the popup `IsOpen` needs to be set to `false`, then back to `true`. Another solution is to move the `RotateTransform` from the `Popup` to the `Image`.